# stop a function in javascript after a certain result has been reached

Tags: javascript, html, function, addeventlistener

Im new to programming and for the final assignment of this 'class' is to create a website with the things we learned. I decided to make like a math game website. This is how the game looks. So in every empty block you have to fill in the number that together with the number next to it, is the sum of the number above

[image]

I need help with the code beneath here. I want to display a message when not everything is filled in. This works. When it is filled in, it displays the score. So if al answers are correct is displays a score of 10. When everything is incorrect it displays a score of 0.

I want to stop this function after the score has been given but i don't know how. It doesnt matter if the score is 10 or 0 or 3. I want it to stop. So if then you would click the button again, it won't affect the score. I just can't seem to figure this out. This is the part of the code where this is executed. Some things in here (like the setAttribute) are for another part of the code.

```
const correctAnswers2 = [
"53",
"28",
"25",
"17",
"11",
"14",
"6",
"5",
"7",
"6",
];

const button2 = document.getElementById("checkbut2");
var score2 = 10;

function Check2(antwoord2, index) {
    var inputs2 = document.querySelectorAll('#o2r1, #o2r2c1, #o2r2c2, #o2r3c1, #o2r3c2, 
    #o2r3c3, #o2r4c2, #o2r4c3, #o2r5c1, #o2r5c5');
    if (correctAnswers2.includes(antwoord2)) {
        inputs2[index].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
        inputs2[index].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        score2--;
        document.getElementById("check2Text").innerText = "Je hebt " + score2 + " punten 
        gescoord";
    }
    document.getElementById("check2Text").setAttribute("clicked", "true");
}



function CheckAwnser2() {

    let o2r1 = document.getElementById("o2r1").value;
    let o2r2c1 = document.getElementById("o2r2c1").value;
    let o2r2c2 = document.getElementById("o2r2c2").value;
    let o2r3c1 = document.getElementById("o2r3c1").value;
    let o2r3c2 = document.getElementById("o2r3c2").value;
    let o2r3c3 = document.getElementById("o2r3c3").value;
    let o2r4c2 = document.getElementById("o2r4c2").value;
    let o2r4c3 = document.getElementById("o2r4c3").value;
    let o2r5c1 = document.getElementById("o2r5c1").value;
    let o2r5c5 = document.getElementById("o2r5c5").value;


    const emptyFeedback = 'Niet ieder vakje is ingevuld!';

    if (o2r1 == "" || o2r2c1 == "" || o2r2c2 == "" || o2r3c1 == "" || o2r3c2 == ""
       || o2r3c3 == "" || o2r4c2 == "" || o2r4c3 == "" || o2r5c1 == "" || o2r5c5 == ""){
       document.getElementById("check2Text").innerText = emptyFeedback;
    } else {
       const gegevenAntwoord2 = [o2r1, o2r2c1, o2r2c2, o2r3c1, o2r3c2, o2r3c3, o2r4c2, 
       o2r4c3, o2r5c1, o2r5c5];
       const len2 = gegevenAntwoord2.length;
       document.getElementById("check2Text").innerText = "Je hebt " + score2 + " 
       gescoord.";
       for (var i = 0; 1 < len2; i++) {
           Check2(gegevenAntwoord2[i], i);
       }
    }
}


button2.addEventListener("click", CheckAwnser2);
```

I'm not a native English speaker so I hope you understand what I mean. And I hope you can help me! :)

Comment: If I understand correctly.. you could have a boolean like `let submitted = false` at the beginning of your script. Once the user gets their score, set it to true. Then in your CheckAnswer2 function, add `if(submitted) {return}` which will exit out of the function without running the rest of the code.

Comment: What is the function you want to stop running?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the function to only be executed when you first press the button, you could just add a boolean variable that stores, whether the score has been already calculated. Then at the beginning of your function you return it, if the variable is true:

```
let calculatedScore = false;

function CheckAwnser2() {
  if(calculatedScore) return;
  // ... your code

  if(o2r1 == "" || o2r2c1 == "") { //Simplified here
    // ...
  } else {
    // ...
    calculatedScore = true;

  }

}
```

Comment: I thought this would work. Unfortunately it doesn't. If I change it exactly like you suggested, it doesn't change anything. And if I do this instead: `if(calculatedScore = true)` I can't click the button at all. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for commenting again. I still don't know why it doesn't work, because it seems very logical. But i got to fix it with an attribute. Same kind of logic haha. Thanks!